# Ploughed fields via moduli

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, graphical-output

Let \$R, C\$ be positive integers and let \$0 < s \leq 1\$. Consider the \$R \times C\$ **matrix** \$\mathbf M\$ defined as
\begin{equation}
M(i,j) = \frac{\mathrm{mod}\,(j, i^s)}{R^s}, \quad i = 1, \ldots, R, \quad j = 1, \ldots, C
\end{equation}
where \$\,\mathrm{mod}\,\$ denotes the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation): for \$a,b > 0\$ not necessarily integer, \$\mathrm{mod}\,(a,b) = c\$ if and only if \$0 \leq c < b\$ and \$a = b\cdot k + c\$ with \$k\$ integer.

Note that \$0  \leq M(i,j) < 1\$.

The matrix \$\mathbf M \$ can be displayed as an image, where the value of each entry determines the color of a pixel, using a **colormap** to translate numbers between \$0\$ and \$1\$ into colors. The simplest colormap is to directly consider each number as grey intensity, with \$0\$ corresponding to black and \$1\$ to white.

As an example, \$R=500\$, \$C=800\$, \$s=0.8\$ with the grey colormap give the following image:

[image]

## The challenge

Given two positive integers \$100 \leq R, C \leq 2000 \$ and a number \$0 < s \leq 1\$, display the above defined matrix \$\mathbf M\$ as an image. You can use any colormap of your choice, not necessarily consistent across images, as long as it satisfies the very lax requirements described next.

## Colormap requirements

1. At least \$16\$ different colours.
2. Reasonably gradual changes between adjacent colours.
3. The first and last colours should be clearly different.

Although the terms *reasonably gradual* and *clearly different* are somewhat subjective, this is not likely to be a contentious point. The sole purpose of these requirements is to prevent abuse. If your programming language offers a default colormap, it is most likely fine. If it doesn't, using grey is probably the shortest option.

## Additional rules

- **Graphical output** is required, with output being [flexible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/default-acceptable-image-i-o-methods-for-image-related-challenges) as usual.
- The image should have the correct **orientation**, with \$M(1,1)\$ corresponding to the upper-left corner.
- The image should have the **aspect ratio** given by \$R\$ and \$C\$. That is, each entry of \$\mathbf M\$ should correspond to a square pixel.
- If the image is output by displaying it on the screen, it is not necessary that each screen pixel corresponds to an image pixel. That is, the **display scaling is flexible** (but the aspect ratio should be kept).
- **Auxiliary elements** such as axis labels, grid lines or a white frame are not required, but are allowed.
- [Programs or functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) are accepted. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test cases

Each of the following uses a different colormap, to illustrate some possibilities (and not incidentally to produce lively pictures).

| Inputs: `R`, `C`, `s` | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `500`, `800`, `0.8` | [image] |
| `600`, `1000`, `0.7` | [image] |
| `800`, `800`, `0.9` | [image] |
| `500`, `900`, `1` | [image] |
| `700`, `1200`, `0.6` | [image] |
| `200`, `250`, `0.3` | [image] |

Comment: Can we output as a matrix of brightness values rather than the standard matrix of tuples of (R,G,B) (which would end up just being the same brightness value repeated 3 times to make gresycale)?

Comment: @pxeger Graphical output is required, so you can't just output a matrix. But there are image formats such as [`pgm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#File_formats) that are close to that

Comment: I just want to say that the last example output has some very interesting moirés once your eyes stop burning

Comment: @UnrelatedString Which is precisely why I chose it (the moiré, not the burning) :-D

Comment: [A matrix is a standard output method for graphical challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9104)

Comment: @pxeger I didn't know that, sorry. Go ahead then. Any ouput format that has consensus is fine

Comment: @pxeger But note that that post says a matrix _of RGB values_ (so a sort of _3D_, not 2D, array)

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I what I get is very dark and dull compared to your render examples.

Comment: @Arnauld If it's dark, maybe you haven't normalized the values properly with respect to the colormap? I'm using colormaps that range from 0 to 1, and the values in `M` have approximately that range

Comment: What part of this did you consider the "meat" of the challenge while writing it? If a matrix is OK, it seems like it boils down to two loops/ranges and the formula `j%i^s/r^s` verbatim from the post, which does not look like it admits much clever tricks. If the output is PGM then there's a bit more to golf. So, I want to make sure that permitting matrix output doesn't water down your vision for this challenge.

Comment: @Lynn Graphical output was (is) an important part of the challenge. Just outputting a matrix waters it down, yes. But that doesn't seem to be allowed by the meta post about image formats. Admittedly there are formats that are close to just the matrix, but they have to be accepted

Comment: @LuisMendo what do you mean they have to be accepted? [This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9104) is +15/-2 - what more do you want?

Comment: @pxeger I mean that formats with large consensus, such as the one you mention, are accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 39 bytes

```
sImage@Array[Mod[#2,#^s]&,{##}]/#^s&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7v/j9pIWeuYnpqQ6ORUWJldG@@SnRykY6ynHFsWo61crKtbH6QLba/4CizLwSh7RoAz2L2GhTAwMdCwOD2P8A)

Input `[s][R, C]`.

[image: Test cases run in Mathematica]

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 131 bytes

```hs
f=fromIntegral
u=unwords.map show
a%b|a>b=(a-b)%b|1<2=a
(r#c)s="P2":u[c,r,99]:[u[round$f j%(f i**s)/f r**s*99|j<-[1..c]]|i<-[1..r]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc27CoMwGEDh3acIXiARTVUoqJjuhRYKHSVDvKRqNcofg4vvboVO59tOJ/S3HcfjkEzCPN3V2n5AjJZhRm0zNJpOYkG6mzdLeNUubhXDIqzI6bhImLAwODXRzH4ldm7KOoAgy3hemhJmoxpXosHDEvW@r8lFIjjrZ9k@FGEZU1pzvvd/AufHJHrFzt8TLWZ9r/BQyEX4GjlpRCKaHj8)

`(r#c)s` returns the lines of a PGM file.

After writing it like this, I learned I could probably just return a matrix of float values but I don't think that's very interesting.

[image]

Comment: Allowed formats are the ones with consensus [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9093/36398). Outputting just the matrix is not one of thoese formats, I think

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 51 bytes

```
load'viewmat'
1 :'[:viewmat(|~^&u)"0~/&(1+i.)%u^~['
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/Pyc/MUW9LDO1PDexRJ3LUMFKPdoKytWoqYtTK9VUMqjTV9Mw1M7U01QtjauLVv//HwA)

A J adverb, which uses the library function `viewmat` to do all the heavy lifting -- we merely need to construct the matrix values.

Assuming the adverb has been assigned to `f`, called like:

```
500 (0.8 f) 800
```

### 500 800 0.8

[image: 500 800 0.8]

### 200 250 0.3

[image: 200 250 0.3]

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>116</s> <s>114</s>118 bytes

-2 thanks to some basic pointers from hyper-neutrino
+4 to correct an off-by-one error, thanks Tipping Octopus

```python
from matplotlib.pylab import*
def M(R,C,s):
 imshow([[j%i**s/R**s for j in range(1,C+1)]for i in range(1,R+1)]);show()
```

Fairly straightforward, my first code golf attempt so I may be missing something easily golfable. Executes nested list comprehension inside the imshow() to immediately create image. Needs the show() to actually display the image.

### 700, 1200, 0.6

[image: 700, 1200, 0.6]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange! If you move the import out of the function, you can save a byte for the indentation. Also, you can inline statements within a function by putting them on one line and separating them with semicolons, which saves more indentation.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino thanks for the tips! I had assumed the import statement needed to be inside the function definition, but it's good that it doesn't!

Comment: Technically you need `range(1,R+1)` and `range(1,C+1)`, though that's likely golfable

Comment: You can golf it a bit more with: `def f(R,C,s):imshow([[-~j%i**s/R**s for j in range(C)]for i in range(1,R+1)]);show()`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript + HTML, 156 bytes

```javascript
(R,C,s)=>{for((w=x=>document.write(x))`<table cellspacing=0>`,i=0;i++<R;)for(w`<tr>`,j=0;j<C;)w(`<td bgcolor=#${((++j%i**s*16/R**s|0)*273).toString(16)}>`)}
```

- -7 bytes by Shaggy

```js
; (function run() {

f=

(R,C,s)=>{for((w=x=>document.write(x))`<table cellspacing=0>`,i=0;i++<R;)for(w`<tr>`,j=0;j<C;)w(`<td bgcolor=#${((++j%i**s*16/R**s|0)*273).toString(16)}>`)}

R = /*R{*/500/*}*/;
C = /*C{*/800/*}*/;
s = /*s{*/0.8/*}*/;

document.write(`
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <label> R = <input id="inputR" type="number" step="1" value="${R}" oninput="UpdateJS()" /></label><br />
  <label> C = <input id="inputC" type="number" step="1" value="${C}" oninput="UpdateJS()" /></label><br />
  <label> s = <input id="inputS" type="number" step="0.01" value="${s}" oninput="UpdateJS()" /></label><br />
  <form action="${location.href}" method="post">
    <input id="inputJs" type="hidden" name="js" />
    <input type="hidden" name="css" />
    <input type="hidden" name="html" />
    <input type="hidden" name="console" value="false" />
    <input type="hidden" name="babel" value="false" />
    <button type="submit">Draw</button>
  </form>
</div>
`)

f(R, C, s);

UpdateJS = function () {
  R = inputR.value;
  C = inputC.value;
  s = inputS.value;
  js = `; (${run}());`
    .replace(/\/\*R\{\*\/.*?\/\*\}\*\//, `/*R{*/${R}/*}*/`)
    .replace(/\/\*C\{\*\/.*?\/\*\}\*\//, `/*C{*/${C}/*}*/`)
    .replace(/\/\*s\{\*\/.*?\/\*\}\*\//, `/*s{*/${s}/*}*/`);
  inputJs.value = js;
};

UpdateJS();

}());
```

Comment: [158 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYxBDoIwEEWvQqImMxQRNMEFDBtugBcASiVtkJJShQQ5O9bVS17e/6r@1BM3crTnQbdi36EMimBCytenNgAzLZS3mr9fYrDhbKQVsCBWma2bXnhc9P001lwOHUV5FUiKUsZkRmWK//3sQuO8ojhVGRUpzuBU6zUd1702dDiuAIqxk/T9yY@TS@n4jdC/3m8YWv2wxn1DnOCWV7jt@w8)

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK) + `iKe`](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 61 bytes

```
{w::y;h::x;p::pow[;z];,(;gray;+_255*((p 1+!h)!\:/:1+!w)%p w)}
```

[Try it online!](https://johnearnest.github.io/ok/ike/ike.html?key=xhQWqes_)

Shortened heavily and made to work with the help of JohnE and coltim at [the k tree.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90748/the-k-tree)

A function which takes input as `R, C, s`.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 66 bytes

```r
function(R,C,s)cat('P2',C,R,99,(99*outer(1:C,(1:R)^s,`%%`))%/%R^s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pfkJNfmp6RmhKflpmak2L7P600L7kkMz9PI0jHWadYMzmxREM9wEgdyAnSsbTU0bC01MovLUkt0jC0ctYBEkGaccU6CaqqCZqaqvqqQXHFmmhGapgaGOhYALGeheZ/AA)

I kinda think that [pajonk's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231106/95126) is close to the shortest possible using [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s built-in graphics...  so here's a completely different approach, which actually turns-out to be 4 bytes shorter...

Outputs the contents of a greyscale [PGM file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PGM_example).  At least on my laptop using Apple's 'Preview' program, the newline characters separating lines appear to be superfluous.

Here's Preview's display of the the output of `ploughed_field(500,800,.8)`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <strike>90</strike> 73 bytes

```
from pylab import*;ion()
def M(R,C,s):imshow(-~r_[:C]%c_[1:R+1]**s/R**s)
```

Heavily based on Danica's answer, I would have commented but I have 0 reputation.

Shorter import statement

`ion()` to show instead of `;show()`

`arange` (from `numpy.arange`) array approach for faster performance and fewer bytes

remove def function indent

```
   from pylab import* 
   ion()
   def M(R,C,s):imshow((arange(C)+1)%(arange(R)+1)[:,None]**s/R**s)
```

Thanks to ovs this shortens to 74 bytes

And a `-~` trick removes 1 byte from `r_[1:C+1]`

Comment: [Welcome](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange) to CGCC! numpy has the builtins [`r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) and [`c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html), which concatenate arrays and slices along different axis. In this case, they can be used to shorten the expression to `r_[1:C+1]%c_[1:R+1]**s/R**s`

Comment: Thank you for teaching me something new! That is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>84</s> 70 bytes

*-14 bytes thanks to [@Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*

```r
function(R,C,s)image(outer(1:C,(R:1)^s,`%%`)/R^s,c=rainbow(64),as=R/C)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCoAgEADQ0wgzMKRCRQiuvIEHiEwyXKTgh45vLR68MoIeoSffYk5gyVDF@Lj7gtzbVUAqQ2CVxL3SwdiB3P7zuriYzvzCOiO5qi03OAIsQtD2E9OG4wM)

[Try it on rdrr.io with graphical output](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(R%2CC%2Cs)image(outer(1%3AC%2C(R%3A1)%5Es%2C%60%25%25%60)%2FR%5Es%2Cc%3Drainbow(64)%2Cas%3DR%2FC)%0Af(500%2C800%2C0.8))

Comment: [70 bytes](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(R%2CC%2Cs)image(outer(1%3AC%2C(R%3A1)%5Es%2C%60%25%25%60)%2FR%5Es%2Cc%3Drainbow(64)%2Cas%3DR%2FC)%0Af(500%2C800%2C0.8))...

Comment: (or an *even more* brightly-coloured version for [69 bytes](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(R%2CC%2Cs)image(outer(1%3AC%2C(r%3DR%3A1)%5Es%2C%60%25%25%60)%2FR%5Es%2Cc%3Dhsv(r%2FR)%2Cas%3DR%2FC)%0Af(500%2C800%2C0.8)) - unless there are possible inputs with R<16 but that still need ≥16 colours)...

Comment: Hm.  Please ignore the 69-byter: there are *lots* of possible inputs with R<16 that need many more colours...

Comment: [66 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231117/95126) but I posted this one myself!

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 137 bytes

```
func[r c s][i: make image! to[]as-pair c r k: 0
repeat y r[repeat x c[i/(k: k + 1): to 1.1.1 to[](to 1 x %(y ** s)/(r ** s)* 255)]]?(i)]
```

`f 500 800 0.8`

[image]

Comment: Very appropriate colormap for a Red answer :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo Indeed :)